# Edit WooCommerce Shop page

Tags: woocommerce

On the shop page, products are shown as collection of smaller images with the product title underneath as a link to the product page and then price and add cart underneath that. I want to add each product's category directly underneath the product title also as a link. Does anyone know how I can easily do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I haven't tried anything as I do not know which file to edit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create folder 'woocommerce' in your theme and copy folder 'templates' in plugins 'woocommerce' to this. Edit anything on file copy in theme.